# If $(V,\|\cdot \|)$ is a finite dimensional space, then all norms are equivalent.

Tags: normed-spaces

I want to show that if $(V,\|\cdot \|)$ is a finite dimensional space, then all norms are equivalent. I have shown that if $\dim V=m$ all norms $$\|x\|_p=\sqrt[p]{x_1^p+...+x_m^p}$$ 
are equivalent, but how to show that for an unspecified norm $\mathcal N$ on $V$, there is a $p$ and two constante $A,B>0$ such that $$A\|x\|_p\leq \mathcal N(x)\leq B\|x\|_p$$
for all $x\in V$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$.

Define $\Vert v \Vert_1:=\sum |a_i|$ provided that $v:=\sum a_i v_i$.

Given an arbitrary norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert$, it holds that for $z\in V$, it holds that $\Vert z\Vert \leq \sum |a_i|\Vert v_i\Vert$.

$\Vert z \Vert\leq \Vert z\Vert_1 \max \Vert v_i\Vert $.

Take $M:=\max \Vert v_i\Vert$.

Conversely, we need some compactness...

Consider $S:=\left\{ z\in V; \Vert z\Vert_1=1 \right\}$, which is compact (Heine-Borel Th.),

and $\Vert\cdot\Vert : (V,\Vert\cdot\Vert_1)\rightarrow R$ is a continuous application (indeed, we saw that $\Vert \Vert \leq M \Vert \Vert_1 $).

Then it attains a minimum on $S$. Put $z_0\in S$.

Therefore, for all $z\in V$ $z\neq 0$
$\Vert \frac{z}{\Vert z \Vert_1} \Vert \geq \Vert z_0\Vert$. Then
$\Vert z\Vert\geq \Vert z \Vert_1 m$, with $m:=\Vert z_0\Vert$.